# if no results from xml api call then

Tags: php, xml, api

I'm running a basic api call and it returns a xml file..i go through the data and set them equal to variables and then echo..all works fine unless there are no results and then it is just blank. How can I add an if statement to check if the api call returned any results?

```
 if($url_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' && (!empty($searchCode))) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($searchCode);
foreach ($xml->result->result as $result):
    $cake=$result->{'cakename'};
    $icecream=$result->{'icecreamname'};


   echo "<ul class='cakes' >";
        echo "<li>$cake and $icecream</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: presumably $searchCode is the result of your api call? You've already got the `!empty()` to check if there was anything returned... or does the api return something regardless of success/failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for the function [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php). Use it like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($searchCode);
if(!$xml 
  || !property_exists($xml, 'result')
  || !property_exists($xml->result, 'result')) {
    die('no results');
}
```

Of course you can elaborate on this the have a more detailed error message.